# Updating Puppeteer from 20.9.0 to 22.0.0

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, chrome-for-testing

We currently use version 20.9.0 of the puppeteer library. Have been trying to update and move to new versions.

Whether it is using our custom process, or simply tying to get the example to work, it does not. My assumption is there is something in the setup. However, I have added both name versions of the config.js to the package root. Chromium is still installed from the previous version. It seems to launch one window and just gets stuck. Using the dev tools setting also proves not very helpful. My understanding is that after 20.9, it was moved to Chrome for Testing but have not found anything useful in how this setup might be different. Any help would be appreciated!